# c++ strings and regular expression

Tags: c++, string

only a month ago, I started learning coding because I found out that I like it. I opted for C++, though I know there are languages out there that are easier to learn for a beginner, but up to know, I'm doing quite well. Two days ago, I started writing a little program containing these lines:

```
string input {"This is the example"};
string b {"is"};
regex r {R"(\s*\is\s*)"};
```

The goal here is to search with the regular expression r in string input for the word or the words that string b contains. THe content of string b comes from a file. If I directly write the word I'm looking for in the regular expression (like I did above with 'is'), then it works, but how do I achieve that the word that string b contains automatically appears in the regular expression? I tried several things, but they all failed because if I try to insert the name of b (for example like this: regex r {R"(\s*\"b"\s*)"};), then the expression doesn't search for the content of b.

Can anyone please help me by writing these lines correctly so that I see what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: _"Gimme teh codez pls"_ in nice disguise or what?

Comment: Do you know how to concatenate strings?

Comment: No, no nice disguise. I tried everything I know of so far, only now I decided to aks for help. I just learn better by looking at examples so that I can transfer this knowledge to other problems.

I've not yet concatenated strings.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are using curly braces instead of parenthesis. So you might getting syntax error.

Syntax : datatype identifier(literal); //declaration

function(arguments); // function call

identifier = function(arguments); // function call with return

Refer below tutorial:

Finding a Regex Match

Call std::regex_search() with your subject string as the first parameter and the regex object as the second parameter to check whether your regex can match any part of the string. Call std::regex_match() with the same parameters if you want to check whether your regex can match the entire subject string. Since std::regex lacks anchors that exclusively match at the start and end of the string, you have to call regex_match() when using a regex to validate user input.

Both regex_search() and regex_match() return just true or false. To get the part of the string matched by regex_search(), or to get the parts of the string matched by capturing groups when using either function, you need to pass an object of the template class std::match_results as the second parameter. The regex object then becomes the third parameter. Create this object using the default constructor of one of these four template instantiations:

```
std::cmatch when your subject is an array of char
std::smatch when your subject is an std::string object
std::wcmatch when your subject is an array of wchar_t
std::wsmatch when your subject is an std::wstring object
```

When the function call returns true, you can call the str(), position(), and length() member functions of the match_results object to get the text that was matched, or the starting position and its length of the match relative to the subject string. Call these member functions without a parameter or with 0 as the parameter to get the overall regex match. Call them passing 1 or greater to get the match of a particular capturing group. The size() member function indicates the number of capturing groups plus one for the overall match. Thus you can pass a value up to size()-1 to the other three member functions.

Putting it all together, we can get the text matched by the first capturing group like this:

```
std::string subject("Name: John Doe");
std::string result;
try {
  std::regex re("Name: (.*)");
  std::smatch match;
  if (std::regex_search(subject, match, re) && match.size() > 1) {
    result = match.str(1);
  } else {
    result = std::string("");
  } 
} catch (std::regex_error& e) {
  // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Comment: It's always nice if you link to the source, in case of tutorial: http://www.regular-expressions.info/stdregex.html